# TestNG for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, testng

I wrote an application using JavaFX. I am new to testing frameworks and I understand that when we write a method using @Test annotation, we don't need to provide a main method as we usually do in Java programs.

But the main method of JavaFX applications is something like,

```
public class App extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("Some function here which need the primaryStage");
    }
}
```

And I want to unit test some methods which should be called after this method is started and the GUI (stage with a scene) is shown on the screen.

e.g -

```
public void fun1(){
    // Do something. But the start method should be called before this method
}
```

How do I achieve this functionality using the annotations in TestNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a build management tool like **Ant** or **Maven** to do the build and testing of same build consecutively. These tools provide separate directory for application code and test code, in a single project.

Otherwise, you have to run one sandbox(cmd terminal) for running the javaFX application and another box(terminal) for running the testNG classes. Regardless of the point that application code and test code are placed in a single project or different project.